# Add exture to opposite side of face

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

Is there a way to put a separate texture on the opposite side of a face, without extruding it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use *Input > Geometry > Backfacing* as factor:

[image]

Comment: How do I add an image on ones side? I added a picture to the original question to show what I tried after you answered.

Comment: plug the image texture you want into one of the MixRGB color input, and another image texture into the other one. I'm not sure how you've unwrapped the whole box though

Comment: I got that to work. It was giving me problems because I had the solidify modifier on it. I deleted solidify and it works. How would I add thickness now though? If I add solidify the nodes don't work.

Comment: if you use a Solidfy modifier, this should answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176005/how-can-i-apply-a-different-material-during-after-using-solidify-modifier

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that, mostly because of the difference in menus / versions, but I clicked on "fill" and "only rim" and that worked. Thanks.